# Query sql server table in azure databricks

Tags: apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am using the below code to query a sql server table **hr.employee** in my azure sql server database using azure databricks. I am new to spark sql and trying to learn the nuances one step at a time.

**Azure Databricks:**

```
%scala
val jdbcHostname = dbutils.widgets.get("hostName")
val jdbcPort = 1433
val jdbcDatabase = dbutils.widgets.get("database")
val jdbcUrl = s"jdbc:sqlserver://${jdbcHostname}:${jdbcPort};database=${jdbcDatabase}"

import java.util.Properties
val connectionProperties = new Properties()
 
connectionProperties.put("user", s"${jdbcUsername}")
connectionProperties.put("password", s"${jdbcPassword}")

%scala
val driverClass = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
connectionProperties.setProperty("Driver", driverClass)

%scala
val employee = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "hr.Employee", connectionProperties)

%scala
spark.sql("select * from employee") 

%sql
select * from employee

employee.select("col1","col2").show()
```

I get the below error. Not sure what wrong am I doing. Tried a couple of variations as well and no luck so far.

**Error:**

```
';' expected but integer literal found.

command-922779590419509:26: error: not found: value %
%sql

command-922779590419509:27: error: not found: value select
select * from employee

command-922779590419509:27: error: not found: value from
select * from employee

command-922779590419509:16: error: not found: value %
%scala
```

Comment: use the `spark.sql(query)`?

Comment: Hi @Lamanus, I tried **spark.sql(select * from ommp)** and get error.    **command-922779590419509:26: error: not found: value select spark.sql(select * from ommp)**                                                                                        **command-922779590419509:26: error: not found: value from spark.sql(select * from ommp)**                                                                                           **command-922779590419509:16: error: not found: value % %scala**

Comment: nope, it should be a string, `%scala spark.sql("select * from employee")`

Comment: Hi @Lamanus Tried with `%scala` and get the same error.

Comment: `val dataDF = {
      val query = "select * from hr.Employee"
      sqlContext.sql(query)
    };` This doesn't work either.